# Insert List<string> of Items into DataGrid-Column-Index 2

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I do have a DataGrid. Very simple:

```
<DataGrid Width="320" Height="340" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Filter" Width="Auto"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="*"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

So now I need to insert a List of Strings into the second column.
I have been looking for a nice solution but couldn't find a good one. I thought about doing this with a binding but couldn't get it working to fill just the second column.

In the first column, I want to put checkboxes in front of every string Item.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you mean you want the second column of a row to hold list of strings?

Comment: @Redouane Yes, there are about 70 entries in the list. Those should be displayed in the rows below the header of the second column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually create columns and for the second column use `DataGridTemplateColumn` and provide a `ItemsControl` (or any control that inherit it) as its `DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate` like this:

```
    <DataGrid Margin="4" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Models}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="CheckBox Column Header" Binding="{Binding BindToBooleanPropertyFromModel}"></DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="List of strings">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <ItemContainerTemplate>
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding BindToListPropertyFromModel}">
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </ItemContainerTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

I use `BindToBooleanPropertyFromModel` and `BindToListPropertyFromModel` as placeholders to a name of property of type `bool` and property of type `IEnumrable<T>` that holders list of strings respectively.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that. One final question: Could you explain to me how I create a Binding correctly? The XAML part is clear but what do I have to do on the other hand? Do I just put a Method (Property) behind the ItemSource and it works? Or do I have to do something else in my .cs file?

Comment: Do you usee ViewModel and Models pattern? what do you use as data source to fill the `DataGrid` ?